# Почему не корректно работает связь селекта с owl-carousel 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5, owl-carousel

Здравствуйте!

Использую для слайдера `owl-carousel 2`

Также используется кастомный селект (в данном случае `bootstrap multiselect`)

При выборе `option select` - показывается соответсвующий слайд

но не корректно работает для определенных `option`

Например, если выбрать `option 6, 7, 8` - отображается `5 option и 5 слайд`

Почему так происходит?

Мой код - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lupmwng4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sync1 = $("#sync1");
  var sync2 = $("#sync2");
  var slidesPerPage = 4; //globaly define number of elements per page
  var syncedSecondary = true;

  sync1.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    slideSpeed: 2000,
    nav: true,
    //autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    loop: true,
    responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
  }).on('changed.owl.carousel', syncPosition);

  sync2
    .on('initialized.owl.carousel', function() {
      sync2.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("current");
    })
    .owlCarousel({
      items: slidesPerPage,
      dots: true,
      nav: true,
      smartSpeed: 200,
      slideSpeed: 500,
      slideBy: slidesPerPage, //alternatively you can slide by 1, this way the active slide will stick to the first item in the second carousel
      responsiveRefreshRate: 100
    }).on('changed.owl.carousel', syncPosition2);

  function syncPosition(el) {
    //if you set loop to false, you have to restore this next line
    //var current = el.item.index;

    //if you disable loop you have to comment this block
    var count = el.item.count - 1;
    var current = Math.round(el.item.index - (el.item.count / 2) - .5);
    var selected = current + 1;

    $('#selectId option').prop('selected', false);
    $('#selectId').multiselect('select', selected);
    $('#selectId').multiselect('refresh');

    if (current < 0) {
      current = count;
    }
    if (current > count) {
      current = 0;
    }

    //end block

    sync2
      .find(".owl-item")
      .removeClass("current")
      .eq(current)
      .addClass("current");
    var onscreen = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').length - 1;
    var start = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').first().index();
    var end = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').last().index();

    if (current > end) {
      sync2.data('owl.carousel').to(current, 100, true);
    }
    if (current < start) {
      sync2.data('owl.carousel').to(current - onscreen, 100, true);
    }
  }

  function syncPosition2(el) {
    if (syncedSecondary) {
      var number = el.item.index;
      sync1.data('owl.carousel').to(number, 100, true);
    }
  }

  sync2.on("click", ".owl-item", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $(this).index();
    sync1.data('owl.carousel').to(number, 300, true);
  });

  $('#selectId').on("change", function(e) {
    var number = $(this).val() - 1;

    sync1.data('owl.carousel').to(number, 300, true);
    sync2.data('owl.carousel').to(number, 300, true);
  });

  $('#selectId').multiselect({
    onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
      console.log('Changed option ' + $(option).val() + '.');
    }
  });


});
```

```css
#sync1 .item {
  background: #0c83e7;
  padding: 80px 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sync2 .item {
  background: #C9C9C9;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sync2 .item h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#sync2 .current .item {
  background: #0c83e7;
}

.owl-theme .owl-nav {
  /*default owl-theme theme reset .disabled:hover links */
}

.owl-theme .owl-nav [class*='owl-'] {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.owl-theme .owl-nav [class*='owl-'].disabled:hover {
  background-color: #D6D6D6;
}

#sync1.owl-theme {
  position: relative;
}

#sync1.owl-theme .owl-next,
#sync1.owl-theme .owl-prev {
  width: 22px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

#sync1.owl-theme .owl-prev {
  left: 10px;
}

#sync1.owl-theme .owl-next {
  right: 10px;
}

select {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select class="form-control" id="selectId">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
  <option value="7">Option 7</option>
  <option value="8">Option 8</option>
</select>

<div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>5</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>6</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>7</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>8</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>5</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>6</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>7</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>8</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Спасибо